# Does nginx need any additional configuration to run a hidden service safely?

Tags: onion-services, web-hosting

I know that nginx is much safer than Apache for hidden services, but is there any additional configuration that **needs/should/is recommended** to be done to run a hidden service safely?

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. In **all cases** - *regardless* of the actual web server - you need to use a **FULL ISOLATION** based on VM/LXC to run a webserver, so there will be **NO** technically possible way to determine an external IP address or it's traces. You don't use any NAT/IP-MASQUERADE, just a port-to-port tunneling. I do recommend to use a LXC+static-binaries, it will make a footprint almost-nothing and will minimize an overhead.

Comment: "so there will be NO technically possible way to determine an external IP address or it's traces" why not just VPN?

Comment: it's about an in-code/in-handler "jailbreaking". A possible attack vector. It's a way simplier than VPN in implementation

Comment: Way simpler? Can't you just run `openvpn` and then start Tor?

Comment: OpenVPN requires an external server. LXC does not

Answer (score 0):

Review an nginx hardening guide. There are several of them online. The [nginx mailing list](https://mailman.nginx.org/mailman/listinfo) is probably a great place to start for advice on hardening if you have specific questions about hardening best practices.

When it comes to actual web apps running as onion services, you can use [OnionScan](https://onionscan.org/) to do a basic pen test of your app to see if your IP is leaking any other common problems that onion services have.